# I need some clarification on what happens when I use the spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, operators, unpack

When I use the spread operator on a `NodeList`:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("div")]
```

Does it:

1. Create a new array
2. Convert `document.querySelectorAll("div")` into an array
3. Unpack the values of `document.querySelectorAll("div")` into the array literal (`[]`)

Comment: The spread operator creates a single-level deep copy of the current iterable object. There's some constraints to that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Copy_an_array

It assigns the output to new memory, for which you can point a variable to. It pairs well with map/reduce/sort as it does not modify the original object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NodeList you get back is iterable (in modern environments), so the effect of

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("div")]
```

is the same as it would be to spread from a plain array. It's effectively doing the same thing as

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div"))
```

So yes, a new array is created, then the elements of the query are iteratively copied into the new array. No intermediate array need be built from the NodeList because it's already iterable. You do end up with a plain array.

(*Any* array initializer with spread syntax creates a new array, just like any traditional use of array initializers does; that's the whole point.)

Note that `...` is not, strictly speaking, an *operator*; it's not part of the expression syntax. (Well it is, in that you can think of the array initializer and object initializer syntax to be part of the overall expression syntax, but it's still not an operator.) It's clumsy not to be able to call it an operator however, so I am personally sympathetic.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and putting in the effort to answer this question, although I must say, there still isn't enough jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator allow you to do different things ([**CHECK HERE**](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754)).

In your case you are creating a new array with all the elements from `document.querySelectorAll("div")`

```js
const arr = [...document.querySelectorAll("div")];

    console.log(arr.length);
    console.log(typeof(arr));
```

```html
<div>
  <p>first div</p>
  <div>
    <p>second nested div</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator does not convert the data into an array. It is looking at **own and enumerable properties** of the iterable object you give to it.

Then it copies them where you tell it to :

in an array : `[...obj]`

in an object : `{...obj}`

in arguments: `func(...obj)`

---

A real great guide here about spread operator : https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/

```js
const set = new Set();

set.add('a');
set.add('b');

console.log(typeof set);

console.log(...set);
console.log(...['a', 'b']);
```